# Determine which of the following rings are fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

Have I done it correctly?

> Determine which of the following rings are fields:
>
> a) $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$/$\large_{(x^2+1)}$
>
> b)$(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]$/$\large_{(x^2+1)}$

My resolution:

> a) We know that $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is a field. Then, $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is a PID. We know that $(x^2+1)$ is maximal if the polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible. We have to search for the roots of the form $[a]\in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, such that $[{p(a)]}=[a^2+1]=[0]$. The elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ are $[0]$ and $[1]$:$$
> [p(0)]=[0+1]=[1]\neq[0],
> $$$$
> [p(1)]=[1+1]=[2]=[0]
> $$
>
> so $x^2+1$ is reducible.
>
> b) We know that $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ is a field. Then, $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is a PID. We know that $(x^2+1)$ is maximal if the polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible. We have to search for the roots of the form $[a]\in (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$, such that $[{p(a)]}=[a^2+1]=[0]$. The elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ are $[0]$, $[1]$ and $[2]$:$$
> [p(0)]=[0+1]=[1]\neq[0],
> $$$$
> [p(1)]=[1+1]=[2]\neq[0]
> $$
>   $$
> [p(2)]=[4+1]=[5]=[2]\neq[0]
> $$
>
> so $x^2+1$ is irreducible $\implies (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]$/$\large_{(x^2+1)}$ is a field.

Comment: @AdamHughes I don't know if there are shadow edits that I missed, but what's written seems perfectly alright to me.  It would be good to conclude part a) with "therefore $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ is not a field", but from my reading, he seems to understand this fact perfectly.

Comment: @Slade Huh, I don't see any edit trail either. Perhaps my brain added the letters "ir" to his "reducible." Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @AdamHughes  I didn't edit anything. Thank you both for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! $F[X]/(f(x))$ ($F$ field ) is a field if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{F}[X]$. Then what you've done is correct!

Answer (score 3):

More concisely, for part a), observe that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is not an integral domain, because $(\overline{x+1})(\overline{x+1})=\overline{x^2+2x+1}=\overline{x^2+1}=0$ in the quotient ring. And $\overline{x+1}$ is non-zero element. If it is not an integral domain, it surely cannot be a field.